# access hbase table from java

Tags: hbase

i have created a table in hbase with 12 columns in each row and each column has 8 qualifiers.when i try to read complete row it returns correct value for 1:1 in row 1 but returns null for 1:2
it reads all the columns correctly from 2 to 10....
plz help how to solve this problem
i m using this code for reading....it is inside for loop thar runs fron 1 to 12..

```
train[0][i] = Double.parseDouble(Bytes.toString (r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.toString(i)), Bytes.toBytes("1"))));
train[1][i] = Double.parseDouble (Bytes.toString (r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.toString(i)), Bytes.toBytes("2"))));
train[2][i] = Double.parseDouble (Bytes.toString (r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.toString(i)), Bytes.toBytes("3"))));
System.out.println("train" + i + ": " + train[2][i]);
train[3][i] = Double.parseDouble (Bytes.toString (r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.toString(i)), Bytes.toBytes("4"))));
train[4][i] = Double.parseDouble (Bytes.toString (r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.toString(i)), Bytes.toBytes("5"))));
train[5][i] = Double.parseDouble (Bytes.toString (r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.toString(i)), Bytes.toBytes("6"))));


train[6][i] = Double.parseDouble (Bytes.toString (r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.toString(i)), Bytes.toBytes("7"))));
train[7][i] = Double.parseDouble (Bytes.toString (r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(Integer.toString(i)), Bytes.toBytes("8"))));
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any reason to put this data into multiple column families.  It seems you can put it all in one column and use an addressing scheme like "i_j"  where i and j are replaced by your indexes.  The issue with putting things into multiple column families is that each column family gets its own store file, and thus uses up a lot more cluster resources.  Also consider using the minimum number of bytes for your column family name.

The problem here cannot be diagnosed without seeing both the code that inserts data into the table, and the full code that retrieves data from the table.  Of course, you don't need to repeat lines so gratuitously.  Try something simpler like:

```
byte[] column_family = Bytes.toBytes("a");
for (int i = 0; i < MAX_I; i++) {
  for (int j = 0; j < MAX_J; j++) {
    train[i][j] = Double.parseDouble(Bytes.toString(r.getValue(column_family, Bytes.toBytes(i+"_"+j);
    System.out.println("train["+i+"]["+j+"]: "+train[i][j]);
  }
}
```